# How to achieve multi-record polygon pop ups in qgis2web exports

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, embeddable-web-maps

I have a project with multiple vector layers (imported shapefiles) that I am trying to export as a Mapbox GL JS web map through the qgis2web plugin in QGIS 3.26. I am having two issues with the final product:

1. I have polygon features each containing multiple records with related attribute field data (merged features). The exported web map does not toggle between the polygons records in the pop up window. How can I configure this?
2. It seems that QGIS has automatically renamed my field labels in the attributes table for some of the layers. Even after I edit and save the appropriate field labels in the Properties dialog, they old ones reappear (e.g. “Layer_Name_1”, “Layer_Name_2”, etc.)

I am on a Windows 11 Home OS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please choose your most pressing issue, and [Edit] the question to describe what you've tried, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think only OpenLayers exports from qgis2web support bringing back popups for multiple overlapping fetures at the same location - sorry.
2. Set human-friendly Alias values for your layer fields in QGIS, and those should be used in the export instead of the actual field names (with the numeric suffixes).

Answer (score -1):

I can only help you with qgis2web openlayers export.
If you want to try this route there are some basic rules for setting up a project so that it can be exported with qgis2web.The first thing is to simplify the data by set the layers also as indicated in this guide by hiding the fields that are not of interest http://www.qgistutorials.com/it/docs/3/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html
The layers must be unique and not grouped in QGIS, so export and then recreate the groups in the layerswitcher. You can see how to do it here https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/977
Configuring "inline label" (when exporting with qgis2web) in the various fields the popup will show the data.
The issue of renaming files by adding the final postfix _0 _1 _2 etc .. has been resolved in this github issue https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/1009 (at the bottom of the conversation there are the modified files that must be overwritten with the original qgis2web files)